# How to work with an instance of a model without saving it to mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongoid

The users of my Rails app are receiving a lot of emails (lets say they represent signups from new customers of my users). When an email is received a customer should be created, and the email should be saved as well. However, if the customer already exists (recognized by the email address of the email), the email email should not be saved to the database. I thought this was handled by `Email.new`, and then only `save` if the email address is recognized. But it seems that `Email.new` saves the record to the database. So how do I work with an email before actually deciding wether I want to save it?

Example code:

```
class Email
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :mail_address, type: String
  belongs_to :user,     :inverse_of => :emails
  belongs_to :customer, :inverse_of => :emails

  def self.receive_email(user, mail)
    puts user.emails.size                                                  # => 0
    email = Email.new(mail_address: mail.fetch(:mail_address), user: user) # Here I want to create a new instance of Email without saving it
    puts user.emails.size                                                  # => 1
    is_spam = email.test_if_spam
    return is_spam if is_spam == true
    is_duplicate = email.test_if_duplicate(user)
  end

  def test_if_spam
    spam = true if self.mail_address == "spam@example.com"
  end

  def test_if_duplicate(user)
    self.save
    customer = Customer.create_or_update_customer(user, self)
    self.save if customer == "created"                                     # Here I want to save the email if it passes the customer "test"
  end
end

class Customer
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :mail_address, type: String
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :customers
  has_many :orders, :inverse_of => :customer

  def self.create_or_update_customer(user, mail)
    if user.customers.where(mail_address: mail.mail_address).size == 0
      customer = mail.create_customer(mail_address: mail.mail_address, user: user)
      return "created"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure `.new` is saving the `email` record? If you go to the console and type `Email.new(mail_address: "some_address@example.com", user: User.first).new_record?`, do you get `true` or `false`? If you get `false`, something really weird is going on. But I bet you'll get true, and the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Hi Jason. Thanks for your comment. I just checked in the terminal, and you are 100% correct. It returns `true`. But, check out the edit I have made in the code. When I `puts` the number of emails before `Email.new` it returns `0`, but when I `puts` after, it returns `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to suggest a somewhat fundamental reworking of your function. Try rewriting your function like this:

```
class Email
  def self.save_unless_customer_exists(user, mail)
    email = Email.new(
      mail_address: mail.fetch(:mail_address),
      user: user
    )
    return if email.customer or email.is_spam? or email.is_duplicate?
    Customer.create!(user: user)
    email.save!
  end
end
```

You won't be able to drop that code in and expect it to work, because you'd have to define `is_spam?` and `is_duplicate?`, but hopefully you can at least see where I'm coming from.

I'd also recommend writing some automated tests for these functions if you haven't already. It will help you pin down the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jason. Could you maybe elaborate how this will avoid saving the email to the database? As far as I can see the problem lies in using `Email.new` in the first line.

Comment: Good question. This doesn't directly address that issue. My experience is that simpler code is much easier to debug, so I figure maybe a good first step would be to simplify your code. (This is a good idea even if the simplification doesn't in itself fix the bug.)